# Working with environments in the parallel package in R

Tags: r

I have an R API that makes use of 5 different R files that define different metrics that I use. Each of those files has a number of tasks that I run using the parallel package since they all use the same data, but with different groupings. To avoid having to create and close the clusters in each file, I took out those commands and put them into a cluster.R file. So the structure I have is basically:

---

cluster.R —

```
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)

clusterEvalQ(computeCluster, {
    library(‘dplyr’)
    source(‘helpers.R’)
})

.Last <- function() {
    stopCluster(cl)
}
```

---

Metric1.R —

```
metric1.function <- function(x,y,z) {
    dplyr transformations
}

some_date <- date_from_api_input

tasks <- list(job1 = function() {metric1.function(data, grouping1, some_date)},
    job2 = function() {metric1.function(data, grouping2, some_date)},
    job3 = function() {metric1.function(data, grouping3, some_date)}
)

clusterExport(cl, c('data', 'metric1.function', 'some_date'), envir = environment())

out <- clusterApplyLB(
    cl,
    tasks,
    function(f) f()
)

bind_rows(out)
```

This API just creates different metrics that then fills a database table that holds them all. So each metric file contains different functions and inputs but output the same columns and groupings.

Metric 2-5 are all the same except the custom function is different for each file and defined at the beginning of each file. The problem I’m having is that all metrics are also ran in parallel and I’m having issues working with the environments. What ends up happening is that the job will say that some_date isn’t found or that metric2.function isn’t found in metric5.R.

I use plumber to expose R and each time it starts, it sources the cluster.R file, starts up the clusters with their initializations, and listens for any requests that come in.

When running in series, it works just fine for testing and everything passes as expected but in production when our server runs all the scripts in parallel, the variables and functions I've exported in the clusterExport function either don't get passed in or are getting mixed up.

Should I be structuring it in a different fashion or am I using the parallel package incorrectly for my purpose?